# Incorrect Date Parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, try-cast

Could you help me determine if I am doing something wrong or if this is a SQL Server bug?

I am using a US SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Server. When I set the `DATEFORMAT` I do not get the expected results. Please see the comments in the code.

```
DECLARE @received varchar(50)

--I expect this to fail, but I get June 11, 2012.
SET DATEFORMAT 'ydm' 
SET @received = '11/JUN/12'

SELECT 
     [month]= DATENAME(month, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[day]  = DATENAME(day, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[year] = DATENAME(year, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))


--I expect this to be June 12, 2011, but I get June 11, 2012
SET DATEFORMAT 'ymd' 
SET @received = '11/JUN/12'

SELECT 
     [month]= DATENAME(month, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[day]  = DATENAME(day, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[year] = DATENAME(year, TRY_CAST(@received as datetime ))
```

**Background info on why I try to validate the above instead of using 2011/06/12:**
We get data extracts in flat files from around the world, from a variety of Warehouse Management Systems and from sources with different degree of technical expertise. Sometimes our clients can produce the data and other times, they subcontract to get their data out from their systems. We deal with millions of rows at at time. So we try our best to validate the dates that they submit in the format they submit. Asking for a re-submit is very inconvenient and cost money and delays. Even though we ask for a preferred format, we do not always get it the first time.

Comment: I can't tell you why, but its because `'11/JUN/12'` isn't a valid date format. If you use `'11/06/12'` you get the expected results.

Comment: Don't use strings instead of dates in the first place. Use `date`-typed fields and parameters. That `@received` isn't a date, it's a string that could contain anything, including `potato`, `4/7/2020` and `7/4/2020`. What is the date in each of the three cases?

Comment: It doesn't help, but the argument to [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) isn't meant to be in quotes.

Comment: Why do you assume that `/12` means 2012? Why not 2012? Why reintroduce Y2K, the worst and most expensive failure in IT, on the very year this caused major banks like Lloyd's to go offline? Back in January this was hot news. You can't even claim ignorance when things inevitably go wrong

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that *dateformat* is limited to working with dates that have numeric values in them.

Changing **JUN** to **6** will cause the second example to work as you expected, while the first will return December 6th, 2011.  The reason is because all the supported [date formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date) for the [format argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) correspond to the 1 or 2 digit forms for day and month and the 2 and 4 digits forms for year with optional slash marks (/), hyphens (-), or periods (.) as separators. So for example for **ymd** corresponds to [yy]yy, [m]m, dd and that's it.

I don't know what mechanism in *cast* or *try_cast* causes the fallback behavior.

```
SET DATEFORMAT 'ymd' 
SET @received = '11/6/12'

SELECT 
     [month]= DATENAME(month, CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[day]  = DATENAME(day, CAST(@received as datetime ))
    ,[year] = DATENAME(year, CAST(@received as datetime ))
```

If you need the month as an abbreviation in the middle then it seems it is possible if you use *parse* and ja-JP culture.  The following example will return the result you desired in your second example.

```
SET @received = '11/JUN/12'
SELECT 
     [month]= DATENAME(month, TRY_PARSE(@received AS date USING 'ja-JP'))
    ,[day]  = DATENAME(day, TRY_PARSE(@received AS date USING 'ja-JP'))
    ,[year] = DATENAME(year, TRY_PARSE(@received AS date USING 'ja-JP'))
```

Comment: I have to mention the absurdity of using 2-digit years in the very year that Lloyd's crashed due to 2-digit years and people were sent notices for 90-year-overdue loan installments.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I can use the Try_Parse with the 'ja-JP' culture for parsing that situation. It helps. I added a comment to the question explaining why I am trying to validate that unusual format.

Comment: @AleBel, if this worked can you give the answer a check so nobody else tries to answer.